# file might prevent wine from working

Tags: 14.04, wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I'm new to `ubuntu` . I installed `wine` to install `microsoft office` 
I have folder for `office 2013` in flash memory . i used wine to install `setup.exe` but got

```
Error in FS_Check
The following file is located on a FAT32 filesystem.
It might prevent wine from working

/media/user/USB/setup.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com). It is a more user-friendly version of Wine and has a compatibility check with applications. I usually turn to PlayOnLinux and have not had any troubles with it.

Or just do

`sudo apt-get install playonlinux`

If you want to be more space-efficient, why don't you just move Microsoft Office to your hard drive? That does seem to be the problem.